# Using LOOKAHEAD in nested conditions

Tags: java, javacc

I am maintaining old code that uses [JavaCC](https://javacc.org/) to parse syntax.

My `.jjt` file broadly looks like this:

```
void Top() {}
{
    Bazz() OpenParenthesis() Foo() CloseParenthesis()
}
void Foo() {}
{
    Bar() Blah() A()
}

void A() {}
{
    Z() (B() Z())*
}
void Z() {}
{
    (OpenParenthesis())? X() Y() (CloseParenthesis())?
}
```

Legend:

- `Top` is the main condition before `<EOF>`, enclosed in a method returning an instance of `Node`
- `OpenParenthesis` and `CloseParenthesis` represent literal tokens for `(` and `)` respectively
- The parser is instructed to ignore whitespace

My issue is that with a "simple" input like:

`bazz ( bar blah x y )`

... the closing parenthesis is consumed as part of `Z`'s condition (the `0 or 1`, `?` quantifier), therefore the compulsory closing parenthesis in `Top` produces a syntax error, where the parser would either expect `B` or `<EOF>`.

JavaCC regular expressions do not feature fine-grained quantifiers as Java regex does, so I cannot use a reluctant quantifier for `Z`'s closing parenthesis.

I have read about the `LOOKAHEAD` construct (some tutorial/docs [here](https://javacc.org/tutorials/lookahead)) and figured I could use one to infer whether the ending closing parenthesis should not be consumed by `Z`, thus re-writing `Z` as:

```
void Z() {}
{
    (OpenParenthesis())? X() Y() (LOOKAHEAD(1) CloseParenthesis())?
}
```

I've also monkeyed around with the size of the lookahead.

Unfortunately, either I do not understand the feature, or the lookahead will not work with hierachical syntax such as the one illustrated above.

Among the choices of poor workarounds I have found so far:

- Remove the optional parenthesis from `Z` altogether
- Make the closing parenthesis optional in `Top`

Obviously neither satisfies me at all.

Have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing the intent of your code, but the rule

```
void Z() {}
{
    (OpenParenthesis())? X() Y() (CloseParenthesis())?
}
```

just looks very odd to me.  Do you really want that all of the following sequences can be parsed as Z?

```
( x y )
x y
( x y
x y )
```

If you think the last two should not be parsed as Z, then change the rule to

```
void Z() {}
{
    OpenParenthesis() X() Y() CloseParenthesis()
|
    X() Y()
}
```

---

If you really really really want Z to be the way it is, make a comment and I'll submit a solution that will work, at least for the example above

Comment: I *should* have thought of that, guess I got really confused with understanding the syntax in the first place (as JavaCC is new to me) and overlooked this. Working on the code right now, chances are I will accept your answer later on.